# What this error means "Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 not an error)" I want to create a table in SQL on www.w3schools.com

Tags: sql

I want to create a table in SQL on www.w3schools.com, and always I recive this error "Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 not an error)"

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Owner varchar(40),
    Balance double,
    CreationDate date,
    ExpirationDate date
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The website doesn't give a success code when the table is created. Write a 
`select * from the table` 
created, and you'll see that the table is already created.

Answer (score 0):

if it is SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Owner varchar(40),
    Balance float,
    CreationDate date,
    ExpirationDate date
);
```

If it is MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Owner varchar(40),
    Balance double,
    CreationDate date,
    ExpirationDate date
);
```